Fail to upload .pkg to Microsoft Intune MDM - pkg file doesn't comply with Line-of-business (LOB) requirements
I'm trying to upload a .pkg file to Microsoft Intune MDM as Line-of-business app (LOB). I've created the package using Packages tool (https://github.com/packagesdev/packages).
However, no matter how hard I try to modify my package to comply with LOB rule, I keep getting the following error :
Build number property must be set for the selected Mac LOB app. 

I'm using the following version format in my Distribution file <major>.<mid>.<minor>-<buildNo>
but it doesn't accept it.
What am I missing here ? Does Intune inspect the info.plist file as well ?
Thanks
